# Using MultibitHD to request payment

Tags: multibit

I am moving over from Multibit classic to HD. I am not particularly technical so this may be an obvious question, however I can't find the answer I want in Multibit's help section, so here I am. 
On the HD request payment field, there are places for amount,(in BTC and Fiat currency), Recipient (one of my addresses)QR code label and private notes. Where is the section to fill in the address payment is request from? In classic I could copy and paste the address. In the HD help section it says you can also do this, however I cant see where you enter the details. Have I missed something blindingly obvious? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With HD wallets you get a new address for each payment request so there is no need to paste a previous address

Comment: Thanks for responding but my question is still there. I can see the newly generated address for me - but where is the field to fill in the address I am requesting from.